# Segmentation fault when calling strcpy function

Tags: c

I'm trying solve an exercise 5.7. from ANSI C book:

> Exercise 5.7. Rewrite readlines to store lines in an array supplied by main , rather than calling alloc to maintain storage. How much faster is the program?

Here is my following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ALLOCSIZE 10000
#define MAXBUF 10000
#define MAXLEN 1000
#define MAXLINES 5000

char * lineptr[MAXLINES];

static char allocbuf[ALLOCSIZE];
static char * allocp = allocbuf;

int readlines(char * lineptr[], int nlines);
void writelines(char * lineptr[], int nlines);

int mygetline(char *, int);

void qsort(char * lineptr[], int left, int right);
void swap(char * v[], int i, int j);

int main(void) {
    int nlines;

    if ((nlines = readlines(lineptr, MAXLINES)) >= 0) {
        qsort(lineptr, 0, nlines - 1);
        writelines(lineptr, nlines);
    } else {
        printf("error: input too big to sort\n");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int readlines(char * lineptr[], int maxlines) {
    int len, nlines;
    char line[MAXLEN];

    nlines = 0;
    while ((len = mygetline(line, MAXLEN)) > 1) {
        if (nlines >= maxlines || len == 0)
            return -1;
        else {
            line[len - 1] = '\0';
            strcpy(lineptr[nlines++], line);
        }
    }
    return nlines;
}

void writelines(char * lineptr[], int nlines) {
    while (nlines-- > 0)
        printf("%s\n", *lineptr++);
}

int mygetline(char s[], int lim) {
    int c, i;

    i = 0;
    while (--lim > 0 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        s[i++] = c;
    if (c == '\n')
        s[i++] = c;
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

void qsort(char * v[], int left, int right) {
    int i, last;

    if (left >= right)
        return;
    swap(v, left, (left + right) / 2);
    last = left;
    for (i = left + 1; i <= right; i++)
        if (strcmp(v[i], v[left]) < 0)
            swap(v, ++last, i);
    swap(v, left, last);
    qsort(v, left, last);
    qsort(v, last + 1, right);
}

void swap(char * v[], int i, int j) {
    char * temp;

    temp = v[i];
    v[i] = v[j];
    v[j] = temp;
}
```

I'm unable to figure out this exercise. I have got an error in `readlines` function at `strcpy(lineptr[nlines++], line);` instruction. I don't know why this instruction cause segmentation fault error. Can anyone recommend how to fix segmentation fault error or propose another solution of this exercise?

Comment: `char * lineptr[MAXLINES];` doesn,'t reserve any space for the strings themselves. You're copying your strings to uninitialized pointers

Comment: I changed `char * lineptr[MAXLINES];` to `char * lineptr[MAXLINES] = { '\0' };` and I still have segmentation fault error.

Comment: initializing to 0 won't do you any good. You need to _allocate_ the memory.

Comment: That's because `'\0'` is equivalent to `NULL`. The only way ***that*** saves you is when you `free` a `NULL` pointer, which is benign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char * lineptr[MAXLINES];
```

declares an array of pointers all right, but doesn't initialize any strings.

So when doing

```
strcpy(lineptr[nlines++], line);
```

you're copying your data using an *uninitialized pointer* leading to a *random memory location* leading to ... *undefined behaviour*

Instead, allocate some memory:

```
char *copy = malloc(strlen(line)+1);
strcpy(copy,line);
lineptr[nlines++] = copy;
```

or just

```
lineptr[nlines++] = strdup(line);
```

You'll have to `free` those in the end.

And a nice touch would be to check that `nlines < MAXLINES`

Comment: Oh dear! I forgot that I should use strdup instead of strcpy. Thank you very much :)

Comment: `strcpy` couldn't have modified the passed pointer anyway. That's why `strdup` returns a pointer, which must be assigned to your value